# runAction:onChildWithName: don't work

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I'm learning some Thing About SKAction class and I'm trying to use the method **runAction:onChildWithName:**, for this I'm trying this code:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite0 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sprite1.png"];

sprite0.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
sprite0.name = @"spriteMegamen";
[self addChild:sprite0];
SKAction *action2 = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(120, 120) duration:5];
[SKAction runAction:action2 onChildWithName:@"spriteMegamen"];
```

But the code onChildWithName don't recognize the name of my sprite and doesn't run the action, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is another constructor method for `SKAction`. That is, all it does is create another action that you can run on a node.

So you should have...

```
SKAction *runOnChildAction = [SKAction runAction:action2 onChildWithName:@"SpriteMegamen"];
[self runAction:runOnChildAction];
```

Just a note.

I found all this out purely by reading the documentation for SKAction. You should always be consulting the documentation. It is what it is there for and it is the best way to learn.